# Use XPATH to locate a specific element and then move forward from that element to locate the next table in the tree

Tags: html, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I can identify some text in an html document that precedes the table I am looking for.  I am however struggling with going from the element that contains the text to the table I am trying to locate.

I have a document that has some text.  This text is identified by looking for some words that are within font tags.  There are tables that follow the text - a structure that perhaps looks like

```
my_string = """<html>
<div><p>maybe some words</p>
<div></div>
<div><font>PICKLES are selling well</font></div>
<div><p>maybe some words</p><table><tr><td>123</td></tr></table></div>
<html>"""
```

I am showing the table as a child of the following div, but I want a general case maybe the table is a child of a div or a p that is some unknown elements following the location in the tree where my font is.

I have been able to get to my font and then back to its parent with the following expression

First though

```
test_tree = html.fromstring(my_string)
```

so to find the magic element

```
for e in test_tree.xpath(('//font[contains(text(),"PICKLES")]'):
    magic_element = e
```

Now that I have found the element so that I know that the next table in the tree will be the table I need I have been successful getting back to the main 'trunk' and now from there I want to find the very next table

```
parent = magic_element.xpath('parent::*')[0]
```

when I look at parent it is the correct element for my next step

```
>>> parent
<Element div at 0x2f8a6d8>
```

Now that I have the parent of my font element I want to go down the tree from that spot to find the next table.  I presumed I could use the following code to start scratching around

```
sibling = parent.xpath('following-sibling::')
```

However, this gives me an error message.

Therefore, how can I continue inspecting my document from the element named **parent** since I need to find parent to then proceed to the next step of locating the content I want to extract.

Please note that my 'document is more complicated then what I have above. It would be trivial to find the only table in this example - often there are other tables (dozens) in the document before the element I am looking for and there are potentially dozens following the specific table I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your HTML, adjusted to be well-formed XML, and formatted for ease of reading:

```
<html> 
  <div>
    <p>maybe some words</p>
  </div>  
  <div/>  
  <div>
    <font>PICKLES are selling well</font>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <p>maybe some words</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div> 
</html>
```

this XPath expression,

```
//font[contains(text(),"PICKLES")]/following::table[1]
```

will select the first `table` element in the document following the `font` element whose string value is the given text.

To tie this together with the question and move the answer up from the comments

```
for e in test_tree.xpath(('//font[contains(text(),"PICKLES")]'):
    e_text = e.text_content()  #to illustrate that I can do something with this element
    my_table = e.xpath('./following::table[1]')[0]  #while only one table is found a list is returned with the table as the only element of the list
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to edit your answer though as I want something more general for the text selector but your solution worked great in my real case/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It was useful but it really is not what I am looking for.  Your guidance does help me select the next table but I have to manipulate and work with the initial element - specifically I need the text from that font element - once my code confirms that the text is correct then I need to find the next table your code is very close but in the general case I need to be at the font element before I look for the table

Comment: Do you have a specific follow-up question?

Comment: Well I just don't think my question has been answered.  I want to start at a particular element - your solution has me starting at the top of the document,  I am sorry that was not clear but I can't start at the top because I have to do something with the content of the font element before I then capture and process the table.  I did not add in my question that I was arriving at the font element for a particular reason but it is where I have to start.  I can't start at the top of the document - I have to find the font element - work with the text and then move forward from there.

Comment: If the context is already at the PICKLES `font` element, then simply use `./following::table[1]` to get the next `table` element in the document from that point.

Comment: Got it worked beautifully.  The dot before the path is what I was missing from earlier attempts - thanks This perfectly answers the question